# laravel elasticsearch babenkoivan/elastic-adapter model relation

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, eloquent, laravel-7

I'm looking to use elastic search on a project with model relation.

For now elastic search is working, I've followed this [doc](https://itnext.io/the-ultimate-guide-to-elasticsearch-in-laravel-application-ee636b79419c) who explain how to start with this package :

- elasticsearch/elasticsearch
- babenkoivan/elastic-migrations
- babenkoivan/elastic-adapter
- babenkoivan/elastic-scout-driver

The problem is I need to able to search by relation.

this is my *composant* elastic migration :

```
Index::create('composant', function(Mapping $mapping, Settings $settings){
        $mapping->text('reference');
        $mapping->keyword('designation');
        $mapping->join('categorie');

        $settings->analysis([
            'analyzer' => [
                'reference' => [
                    'type' => 'custom',
                    'tokenizer' => 'whitespace'    
                ],
                'designation' => [
                    'type' => 'custom',
                    'tokenizer' => 'whitespace'    
                ]
            ]
        ]);
    });
```

Here my *categorie* elastic migration :

```
Index::create('categorie', function(Mapping $mapping, Settings $settings){
        $mapping->keyword('nom');

        $settings->analysis([
            'analyzer' => [
                'nom' => [
                    'type' => 'custom',
                    'tokenizer' => 'whitespace'    
                ]
            ]
        ]);
    });
```

My *composant* Model :

```
public function categorie()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Categorie');
}

public function toSearchableArray()
{
    return [
        'reference' => $this->reference,
        'designation' => $this->designation,
        'categorie' => $this->categorie(),
    ];
}
```

and my *categorie* Model :

```
public function toSearchableArray()
{
    return [
        'nom' => $this->nom,
    ];
}
```

So if you look at the composant relation, you can see that the join mapping return the categorie relation. I dont now if I do it right but what I know is that elasticsearch didn't have any relation in the object I'm looking for.

And I didn't find any doc of how to use the join mapping method of the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've found the solution, the problem was in the migration you must use **object** in order to index the belongsToMany relationship like that

```
Index::create('stages', function (Mapping $mapping, Settings $settings) {
            $mapping->text('intitule_stage');
            $mapping->text('objectifs');
            $mapping->text('contenu');
            $mapping->object('mots_cles');
        });
```

and in your model :

```
public function toSearchableArray()
    {
        return [
            'intitule_stage' => $this->intitule_stage,
            'objectifs' => $this->objectifs,
            'contenu' => $this->contenu,
            'n_stage' => $this->n_stage,
            'mots_cles' => $this->motsCles()->get(),
        ];
    }
```

And the result is as expected now

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get "nom" of categorie, write this in *composant* Model instead

```
'categorie' => $this->categorie->nom ?? null,
```

$this->categorie() return the relationship, not the object.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with a belontoMany relation, and I've made the same things in order to get the relation as a nested object, but when I try to populate my index the field "mots_cles" stay empty, I don't understand why.

Here is the migration :

```
Index::create('stages', function (Mapping $mapping, Settings $settings) {
            $mapping->text('intitule_stage');
            $mapping->text('objectifs');
            $mapping->text('contenu');
            $mapping->nested('motsCles', [
                'properties' => [
                    'mot_cle' => [
                        'type' => 'keyword',
                    ],
                ],
            ]);
        });
```

The model :

```
public function toSearchableArray()
    {
        return [
            'intitule_stage' => $this->intitule_stage,
            'objectifs' => $this->objectifs,
            'contenu' => $this->contenu,
            'n_stage' => $this->n_stage,
            'mots_cles' => $this->motsCles(),
        ];
    }

public function motsCles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(MotsCle::class);
    }
```